# ASP.NET Core casts properties to base class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two 'data' classes:

```
public class BaseData
{
    public string BaseDataStuff { get; set; }
}

public class ChildData : BaseData
{
    public string ChildDataStuff { get; set; }
}
```

and a 'container' class:

```
public class Container
{
    public BaseData Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the following controller:

```
public class Controller : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ChildData Data;
    private readonly Container Container;
    public Controller()
    {
        Data = new ChildData()
        {
            BaseDataStuff = "base stuff",
            ChildDataStuff = "child stuff"
        };

        Container = new Container()
        {
            Data = Data
        };
    }


    [HttpGet("data")]
    public ActionResult<BaseData> GetData() => Ok(Container.Data);

    [HttpGet("container")]
    public ActionResult<Container> GetContainer() => Ok(Container);

}
```

The first method just returns the `ChildData` instance. When I run it in swagger, I get the JSON I expect:

```
{
  "childDataStuff": "child stuff",
  "baseDataStuff": "base stuff"
}
```

When I run the second method through swagger, it looks like it casts the `ChildData` instance to `BaseData`. I get the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "baseDataStuff": "base stuff"
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what is happening here please?

Comment: `public BaseData Data { get; set; }`

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy, so what? Isnt the runtime type of Data ChildData?

Comment: It is how `JsonSerializer.Serialize` from `System.Text.Json` works, `Newtonsoft.Json` works normally.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Any idea how I can make it work like I want? That is, serialize it as ChildData.

Comment: It depends on how your web server is built. But it would be extremely wrong. Just a small question: assuming you have a "correct" json with two fields in "data" section, what do you expect as a result of this `var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(jsonStr);`?

Comment: I would expect it do deserialize it back into a container with an instance of ChildData. Is that wrong? Also is my "desired behavior" incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was interesting. See [How to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

There it explains that System.Text.Json does not handle serializing polymorphic objects the way you want prior to .NET 7. There are some work arounds but those allow you to serialize when the root object is polymorpic (Container in you case) but not members of the root (BaseData and ChildData).

In .NET 7 you can do this

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ChildData))]
public class BaseData
{
    public string BaseDataStuff { get; set; } = string. Empty;
}
```

and

```
public class ChildData : BaseData
{
    public string ChildDataStuff { get; set; } = string. Empty;
}
```

and

```
public class Container
{
    public BaseData Data { get; set; } = new BaseData();
}
```

Then this

```
var data = new ChildData()
        {
            BaseDataStuff = "base stuff",
            ChildDataStuff = "child stuff"
        };

var container = new Container 
{
    Data = data
};

jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(container);
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

gives you

```
{"Data":{"ChildDataStuff":"child stuff","BaseDataStuff":"base stuff"}}
```

Which I think is what you want. Of course, going to .NET 7 may not be convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You could try serializing yourself [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1)

```
options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true
};
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(Container, options);
```

or another option, is to explicitly mark them as serializable for the serializer:

```
  [DataContract]
  public class BaseData
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string BaseDataStuff { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class ChildData : BaseData
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string ChildDataStuff { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Of course both are not working as they affect on the root object only.